# Installing VMware tc Server in Spring

Tags: spring, spring-mvc, vmware

This might be a stupid question. I have recently installed Spring by downloading the Spring Tool Suite. Just wondering how I can setup the VMware vFabric tc Server? I have selected VMware when defining a new server, but anyone help me identify the Installation directory and version?